# Django Accesing Model Class From Field Instance

Tags: django

I need to write a function that is passed an instance of a CharField. Is there any way I can figure out what model class this field belongs to?

Comment: Can you post a bit of your code?

Comment: -1 b/c your question needs more explanation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume you mean what ModelForm this field belongs to...

From looking at django.forms.Field and the `__dict__` on a CharField, it appears that the answer is "no".  You'll have to pass the Form or Model class as necessary.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you actually do mean a `Model`, then you can get access to the class (but not, apparently the instance).

```
# This is is a model instance method:
field = self._meta.get_field_by_name('status')[0]
print field.model
```

Note, this uses the `_meta` on the model class, which is *technically* implementation detail. Unlikely to be going away any time soon, though.